# Implicit intent causes the app to crash at button press

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-pendingintent, intentservice

In an attempt to understand how the *implicit intents* works, I wanted to create a layout with two *edittext* and one *button*. In the first *edittext*, the user should enter his/her the email address, and in the second *textview* he/she should enter the email address of the recipient, and when he/she clicks on the *button*, all the component registered for the Action SEND should appear, including my app.

Below are my attempts and the *logcat*:

**UPDATED_JavaCode**

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String from = et_from.getText().toString();
        String to = et_to.getText().toString();
        String data = from + to;

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, from + to);
        //i.setData(Uri.parse(data.toString()));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

**UPDATED_Manifest**:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".EmailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_intents_test01" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="CustomActivity"> </activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</application>
```

**Logcat**:

```
11-15 14:47:19.714: E/AndroidRuntime(18239): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 14:47:19.714: E/AndroidRuntime(18239): Process: com.example.emailactivity, PID:18239
11-15 14:47:19.714: E/AndroidRuntime(18239): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
                    No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=yt (has extras)
                    }
11-15 14:47:19.714: E/AndroidRuntime(18239):     at
                    android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1672)
11-15 14:47:19.714: E/AndroidRuntime(18239):     at
                    android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1442)
11-15 14:47:19.714: E/AndroidRuntime(18239):     at
                    com.example.emailactivity.EmailActivity$1.onClick(EmailActivity.java:46)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ACTION_SEND` does not use `setData()` -- please remove that.

Also, please use the keys documented in [the `ACTION_SEND` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) for your extras.  Note that there is no `"from"` and there is no `"to"`, so you can remove those extras. You will need to provide `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM` to provide the actual content that you are sharing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I removed setData(). now, the are two things:1-i need to pass the two values given in the edittext (from and t) should use `i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, from);` and `i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, to); like this?  2-my app is not listed among the registered components

Comment: @user2121: You can fill *one* value into `EXTRA_TEXT`. You also need to add `setType()` on your `Intent` to indicate the MIME type of the content in `EXTRA_TEXT`. You need to then have a corresponding `<data>` element in your `<intent-filter>` to match on that MIME type.

Comment: kindly, please see the updated code and manifest. the App is not yet showing as a registered component

Comment: @user2121: Use `android:mimeType`, not `android:scheme`, in your `<data>` element: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#mime

Comment: now the manifest looks like this `<activity android:name="CustomActivity"> </activity>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>` and still not showing

Comment: @user2121: Your `<intent-filter>` goes *between* the `<activity>` and `</activity>` tags. You can see this in your `LAUNCHER` `<activity>` element in your manifest.

Comment: Thank you. but how did you know that setData does not work with action.send?

Comment: @user2121: Because the documentation does not mention it. Usually, if an `Intent` action requires a `Uri`, the documentation will explain what the `Uri` is for. More importantly, you don't just make up `Uri` values, as you originally did.

Answer (score 3):

When using implicit intents it is possible that there are no applications that can handle your intent (which, between other problems, seems to be your problem). To avoid this, before calling startActivity() you should first verify that there is at least one application registered in the system that can handle the intent. To do this use resolveActivity() on your intent object:

```
// Verify that there are applications registered to handle this intent
// (resolveActivity returns null if none are registered)
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```